# Adding UIAnimation

Tags: ios, arrays, image, uianimation

I have a ScrollView with paging and I have a button which takes me to an array with image in my scrollView .. Here's my codes

```
-(IBAction)scrollToPage:(id)sender {
    int scrollToPage = 1; 
    int scrollToX = 1-1; 
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollToX*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

I know it's already animated but I need to add custom animation to it for example :"flip horizontal, cross dissolve, etc"

Thanks in advane

Comment: Are you trying to add the animation when the user presses the button?

Comment: Look, When I tap the button there's a new image is appeared with a normal animation .. I want to change this animation :) .. Thank you!

Comment: was my answer helpful at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet to flip the image you have in your `button pressed` action method. This will allow the image to be flipped then you can play around with it to be what you want.

```
UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage 
                     scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Amp .. But actually the button doesn't take me to a specific to use your codes .. It takes me to an image with buttons it's the first array .. What I need to is modify my codes and add an animation to it .. is that possible ? ... anyway I voted up your answer and thank you for your interest :)